# I can not install npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, expo

PS D:\Repos\BANANAFILE> npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

npm ERR!

npm ERR! While resolving: bananafile@1.0.0

npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0

npm ERR! node_modules/react

npm ERR!   react@"^16.14.0" from the root project

npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.12.0" from @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native@0.8.0

npm ERR!   node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native

npm ERR!     @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native@"*" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.2" from react-native@0.68.2

npm ERR! node_modules/react-native

npm ERR!   react-native@"0.68.2" from the root project

npm ERR!   peer react-native@">= 0.58.0" from @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native@0.8.0

npm ERR!   node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native

npm ERR!     @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native@"*" from the root project

npm ERR!   1 more (@react-native-async-storage/async-storage)

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency
resolution.

npm ERR!

npm ERR! See C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-05-22T03_25_52_871Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 4):

as per your log the versions are mismatching,  try to install with `--legacy-peer-deps`

```
npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native --legacy-peer-deps
```